# Contact Form 7: How to check if a shortcode exists on the form body?

Tags: wordpress, forms, filter, customization, contacts

I need check if my custom CF7 form tag is inserted on the form, to create a  simple condition.
I know the function `has_shortcode( $content, 'my-shortcode' )`, but I don't know the var that the CF7 uses.
I dig a lot on google, but nothing help-me.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the shortcodes for each form in the forms list in the cf7 admin page, right next to the form name

Answer (score 0):

maybe its helpful enaugh to do the shortcode and check the length of returned content.

```
if(strlen(do_shortcode('[contact-form-7']) > xxx){
  // exists
}else{
  // not exists
}
```